# Convention when using Reader interface inside select statement

Tags: go, select, blocking, reader

I've wrapped a queue to implement the `Writer` and `Reader` interfaces (for pushing and popping, respectively).

I need to continuously listen to the queue, and handle every message that comes through. This is simple when the queue is represented as a channel, but more difficult otherwise:

```
loop:
    for {
        var data []byte
        select {
            case <-done:
                break loop
            case _, err := queue.Read(data):
                fmt.Println(string(data))
        }
    }
```

What's the proper way to do this? `Read` here is blocking - it waits until the queue has a message.

Is there a better, more idiomatic way to achieve this?

Comment: What is queue? Does it have a way to cancel a read by setting the read deadline or closing it?

Comment: I'm using RabbitMQ, and https://godoc.org/github.com/streadway/amqp#Channel.Consume to read data from it. I can explicitly acknowledge that I'd read from the queue, but I don't think it has read deadline functionality.

Comment: If I understand correctly, Consume returns a channel. Use that channel in the select?

Answer (score 1):

It’s harder to take a synchronous API (like queue.Read as you described above) and make it asynchronous than it is to do the opposite.

The idea would be to create a new goroutine (using, for example go func() {...}) and have that goroutine execute the read and write the output to a channel.

Then the first goroutine would block on that channel and the one it’s already blocking on.

This has the potentially to leave orphaned resources for a little while if the read takes to long but if you have a synchronous API, it’s the best you can do.